# Controlling distance

Tags: edges

I want to move a copy of the right edge of the surface along its top edge for a certain distance (marked with red arrows on the screenshot).[image: distance] To do this, I turn on snapping to edges, select the right edge, press Shift + D, move the cursor along the top edge, but there is no possibility to enter the desired distance from the keyboard... In the lower left corner, coordinates in the global system are highlighted and i can enter them, but it doesn't help me. The difficulty is that neither the surface nor the edges are parallel to any coordinate axes. Does anybody has an idea how to do that, or how else this can be done?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you edge sliding or snapping another edge to that face?

Comment: @MichaelBenDavid
I'm copying the right edge of the face (by pressing "Shift+D") and snapping it to the same face.

Comment: better do this press shift+tab to turn on snapping with increment enabled then press ctrl +r and select the area to cut ( in the middle in this case) and click and then slide until the side that you want to.

Comment: I can move the copy of right edge along the top edge simply with snapping to edges enabled. The main question is how can i make the distance, marked with red arrows on my screenshot, equal exactly 0.02, for example. I want to enter that distance from keybord some how. 
I guess, first of all i need to align the whole face along axes (by pressing S,0,X, for example) than i'll be able to move the edge to the exact distance the way i want, but how to bring the face back to it's first position togehter with the new edge i created?...

Comment: g + x + 0.950 for example, but center the edge first to align it like this, also you can the enable the length in right panel in edit mode for seeing how much has of distance on every edge,as i said is more easier to create a loop cut and then edge slide pressing g twice, with snapping enabled with increment

Comment: I think i don't really understand what do you mean by "center the edge first  to align it like this", but looks like "g + any axe + distance" won't help because neither the surface nor the edges are parallel to any coordinate axes. I didn't get why while sliding a loop cut snapping  with increment should be enabled? What will it change if snapping will be disabled at all?

Comment: is that you wont have an even distance without snapping, if you want the exact measures use it. remember that in the left panel appears the tool properties

Comment: You said "g + x + 0.950 for example". Could you tell me how will it work, if neither the surface nor the edges are parallel to any coordinate axis? If i press it, then the edge will move along X axis on 0.950 and out of the face, right? But i need the edge to be inside the face and to move strictly along the upper edge on exact distance.

Comment: move the edge to the middle of the face first and then move it again like i told you with the number that you want like the example...and for what do you need the edge to be separated from the face?

Comment: I don't need to separate the edge from the face. I'm a newbie in Blender and i don't know how to move the edge to the middle of the face. I attached more screenshots: 1st with global axis of the edge, 2nd - with normal axis of the edge. I know how to move the edge on an exact distance along these axis, but then the edge will leave limits of the face, like on 3rd screennshot, where i moved the copied edge on -0.5 along Z axis of it's normal coordinate system, and as a result, the copied edge crosses the face.

Comment: so i see that you are newbie. ok then so as i said better do what i told you...

Comment: I didn't find where you told me how to move the edge to the middle of the face. Could you please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicating an edge will not cut an edge into the face. The duplicated edge will just hover there, unconnected to the rest of the object. *Probably* what you want is?...

- Select the edge you want to slide along, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> create a Custom Orientation from it. (Check 'Use After Creation').
- Create the edge you want to slide, *in* the face, any old how, eg.  <kbd>K</kbd> cut it with the Knife tool, not worrying about accuracy
- <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> slide it down all the way to the end of the face, where it will be stopped by the end vertices
- <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Your Number</kbd> move the edge back again, to the required distance from the end, parallel to the orientation edge.

.. but this method will work just as well with a duplicated edge, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

ok as i already told youu in comments just create one or two edge loop cuts (if you need the same edge in the other border add two) in the middle of the faces with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> previously before doing this, align the view to <kbd>3</kbd> or <kbd>1</kbd> of the numpad keys and then enable snapping with increment and scroll in a little until you see the grid gets smaller enough and then slide that edge loop, until you see a good "distance" or space bewtween the edge and border edge, check the left panel to see how much did you move it, and repeat the same to the other edge

Comment: I understood the way, you described in comments, but trying to "catch" the needed distance moving the mouse is less precise way then enter this distance through keyboard. But i didn't know that there is possibility to see distances while moving elements, so, thank you too!